# How can I create a new tikz-timing character or modify an existing one?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

I am using the `tikz-timing` package for the first time. I would like to draw a timing diagram which contains a lot of pulses. I would prefer the symbol produced by the `ifsym \ShortPulseHigh` style to the one produced by the `tikz-timing G` character or the `ifsym |` character.

Is it possible to create a new `tikz-timing` character that produces the same symbol as the one produced by the `ifsym \ShortPulseHigh` style or to modify the `tikz-timing G` character to produce the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who may have considered answering my question. I managed to solve the problem after reading the **tikz-timing** package documentation. I solved the problem by defining a meta-character P as shown in the following example:

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
     timing/metachar={P}{0.001L [[timing/slope=0]] 0.4H 0.001L}
  ]
  Pulse & L P L\\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

The above TikZ code works. Here is what it produces.
[image]

Comment: It's amazing what you can do if you read the manual.

Comment: Though it would be more amazing if it produced an MWE @JohnKormylo ;).

Comment: I agree with you @JohnKormylo. I should not have rushed to ask the question before reading the manual thoroughly. Thanks.

Comment: I have found that the width of the low part of the P metacharacter as described here, ie the line before the pulse, varies greatly in width. If you're drawing lines trying to indicate synchronisation, it seems almost random how long the low part will be, up to about 0.5em...